# How to get SQL query on Progress 4GL?

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I want to display all Items and list of Customer Names that bought and does   not bought such item. Columns to display Item, Item Name, Customers Names that bought, Customers Names that does not bought. In SQL it looks like this.

```
 SELECT field1,field2,field3 
    FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 on ... 
    WHERE field3 NOT IN (
          SELECT distinct field3 FROM tbl3 JOIN tbl4 on ...
          WHERE ...)
```

here 4 tables

```
customers      orders             orderlines        items
custid|name|   orderid|custid|    orderid|itemid|  itemid|name
```

Comment: What kind of information do you need per row? Could you give example rows and modify the query to show the real table and columns names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule #1 -- Progress is NOT SQL.  The harder you try to make it SQL the unhappier you will be.

There is some very limited support for "embedded" SQL-89 within the 4GL engine.  If you try to use this because you like SQL better you will become very frustrated very quickly.  It is occasionally useful for a very quick & dirty ad-hoc query but is otherwise not useful.

There is no direct translation between SQL and 4GL.

Queries in the 4gl are very procedural.  Your question is a bit unclear but you might try something similar to:

```
for each customer no-lock:
  for each order no-lock where order.custNum = customer.custNum:
    for each orderLine no-lock where orderLine.orderNum = order.orderNum:
      display customer.custName order.orderStat orderLine.description.
    end.
  end.
end.
```

This example is very crude -- the 4gl supports a lot more functionality including dynamic queries and OO constructs but it is unclear what you actually need.

You could write the code above using a join but it is less clear for a beginner:

```
for each customer no-lock,
    each order no-lock where order.custNum = customer.custNum,
    each orderLine no-lock where orderLine.orderNum = order.orderNum:

  display customer.custName order.orderStat orderLine.description.

end.
```

4gl code does not tend to use a lot of complicated queries.  They are usually built up procedurally and may involve temp-tables.

Indexing is very important.  Unlike many SQL engines, the 4gl uses a static, rule-based, compile-time optimizer.  It knows nothing about data distribution and chooses indexes based on rules.  This may help:

http://pugchallenge.org/downloads2014/374_Still_Dont_Know_About_Indices_PCA2014.pdf

If you want to select records that are NOT in a sub-query the CAN-FIND() function might be helpful although it is not going to be very good for performance.  It will generally result in a table scan.

i.e.

```
for each customer no-lock where not can-find( first order where order.custNum = customer.custNum ):
  /* customers with no orders... */
end.
```

Comment: Just look here, i have made half of this task mb you understand other half like this
for each order,
     each order-line of order where itemid = 9  break by(custid):
     if first-of(custid) then do:
         /* and here i have got custid which didn't buy this items*/
i dont know how to implement somethink like this in SQL NOT IN

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say.  And this site really isn't suited to back and forth conversations refining your requirements.

Comment: Tom, i am newbie at Progress 4GL, i dont know how to explain, i want to know how can i implement "Except" in SQL or "NOT IN"  methods..  and i have no idea how to do this... i have made this with temp-table...  but i think its bad idea...